# How do I find if I have background location services? I only use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION foreground

Tags: android, permissions, localization

I'm currently struggling with being compliant with new google play policies regarding localization permission.

I developed an app to call emergency numbers from (almost) any country in the world and I have a feature that allows the user to click on a button to locate himself and display the corresponding emergency numbers of the country he is in.

My issue is that Google sent me an email to reject my app because I quote : "Feature does not meet requirements for background location access".
The thing is : I do not ask for background location access, so I do not know what to do... I ask for "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" and I start a service declared as foreground.

Here is my manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/er"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/er"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    <service
        android:name=".LocationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:description="@string/emergency_localization"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location"
        android:icon="@drawable/er"
        android:label="@string/emergency_localization_label"
        android:permission="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.location.Geocoder"
    android:required="false" />
```

And the code plugged to the localization button :

```
        findMeBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (!PermissionNeeded()) {
            DisplayIcon(true);
            locationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
            startService((locationIntent));
        }
    });
```

I asked for more information to Google, and the only answer was :

"We have re-reviewed your app, but your declared feature still does not meet the requirements to access location in the background because of the following reason(s):

Users may not expect the app to access their location in the background
It is possible to deliver a similar experience without access to location in the background"

Thank you very much Google for being more explicit...

So I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious somewhere, but since I have no idea where to look at, I really need a new pair of eyes on it...
Thanks a lot by advance !

EDIT : I saw that I was not stoping the service in the onPause method in the main activity, so I added this and tried to publish it again, but same error, apparently I am still asking a background service permission, without currently asking it ... I am now losing faith on this app's future...

Comment: Do you actually need FINE location? Why identifying more or less the country isn't enough?

Comment: Maybe use startForegroundService instead of just startService, [that's how the documentation says](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits)

Comment: startForegroundService is only available starting from API 26, I want to suggest my app to older versions too... I do not understand why I should make a specific call on a service to make it foreground if I already declared it as foreground in the manifest...

Fine location could be argued, I agree, but a coarse location permission should not impact the background/foreground access issue, or am I missing something huge here ?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue, @NicolasChevalier? We are facing the same, and the last 3 submissions *trying* to fix this issue in the blind haven't been successful.

Comment: Hello, actually, yes.
I added an explicit permission to the manifest:

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

and everything was fine. It appears that if this permission is not explicit, the implicit one is background service, even if your service explicitely asks for a foreground one...
        android:permission="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

Since then, I never had any issue. Thanks for the Google developers who made this heresy possible!